# Fading a video clip to black

Tags: c#, video, directshow

I have a requirement to play a video file in C# (with audio) then to be able to fade out the video to a black screen then fade in another video.

I've looked at DirectShow & DirectShowNet however I'm none the wiser. I've got a simple app to play a video with a time counter etc, however I'm flummoxed with filters & graphs.

What direction do I need to go in?

Comment: Is this embedded within a Windows Form?

Comment: I'm open to the best solution, I looked at the DShow stuff as I had seen this do video stuff before.

Answer (score 1):

Create a WPF Apllication and use the MediaElement Control to play the videos. Use the events of the MediaElement (for example MediaEnded) to detect when to start fadeout / switch streaming source / fadein. The easiest way for the fadeout is to change opacity of the Mediaelement.
The MediaElement should be able to play all videos which have a directshow filter installed on your system.

Comment: Cool geoff mentioned that - sounds like the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Antoher nice way is to do it with silverlight - if it fits your requirements. the mediaelement there is very nice and got "out of the box" more features than the wpf mediaelement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WPF?

With WPF you could do this in a variety of ways. eg you could simply animate the video control's ([MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)) opacity.

**NOTE**: you can use WPF controls inside of a Winforms app. See [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DanielMoth/Use-WPF-from-Windows-Forms-projects-in-Visual-Studio-2008) video for how to do this.

Comment: Hadn't thought of WPF, I shall have a gander and see whats involved.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, although I would consider it a hack, would be to draw a black overlay ontop of the viewable area of the video.  You can adjust the transparency of the overlay based on the frame/time of the video.  Essentially, you would fire off a timed event that would slowly remove or add transparency to the overlay based on where in the video you want to starting fading.

Comment: Yes, that sounds a bit too hacky to me. Nice solution however I think the idea is to add more functionality to the app over time, and I see this as perhaps a dead end.